# summation of finite fractional power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was trying to solve the following equation and I don't know how to start:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/7} = ?$$

I could only transform it into the following equation:
$$1^{1/7} + 2^{1/7} + 3^{1/7} + ..... + n^{1/7}$$
Now, how to go on with the solution ?

Comment: there is no closed solution only in terms of zeta and hurwtiz zeta function your series is equal to $ \zeta (-1/7) -\zeta _{H} (-1/7,n+1) $

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/7}=H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{7}\right)}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers.

For "large" values of $n$, the approximation would be
$$S_n=\frac{7 n^{8/7}}{8}+\frac{{n^{1/7}}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\frac{1}{84\,n^{6/7}}
   +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ with $\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{7}\right)\approx -0.386643$. You will recognize that the first term is just $\int_0^n k^{1/7}\,dk$.

Using $n=10$, the exact value should be $\approx 12.46784431$ while the above approximation would give $\approx 12.46784475$ which does not look too bad (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With [Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula $\ds{\pars{\mbox{see}\ \mathbf{\color{#000}{3.6.28}}\ \mbox{in A & S Table}}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_16.htm):
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{1/7} & =
{65 + 210n + 147n^{2} - 65\pars{n + 1}^{6/7} \over 168\pars{n + 1}^{6/7}} +
\,\mrm{O}\pars{\bracks{n + 1}^{\,-20/7}}
\end{align}
In the following table:

- The middle row is the *original* sum.
- The right row is the *Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula*.

[image]